# Choose default activity on NFC detect

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, nfc

I'm working on an android app (NFC enabled) where i have 3 Activity classes

1. Splash Activity (App start from here)
2. Authentication Activity (App wait here for NFC authentication)
3. Main Activity (Rest of the application work here)

In all activities i need to enable NFC.

1. If app not in foreground, on tab NFC application start in Splash activity, check the authorization, if success skip `Authentication activity` and go to Main activity.
2. If not authorized then app will go to `Authentication activity` and wait for NFC swipe.
3. In Main activity i use NFC to record some data.

So in all the activity i have to register

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
  android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
  android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

But when running the app, (when app not running foreground) Phone showing `Choose an action` dialog to choose an activity (where all choices are app name only)

Advice me to fix this issue.

My AndroidManifest look as follows

```
<application
    android:name=".util.Common"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- NFC Tech Filter -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.AuthActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_auth"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that could work would be to explicitly put a NDEF record with a AAR (Android Application Record) on the tag, so that tapping the tag when the app is not in the foreground starts the app.
For any other solution I assume you need to fine-tune the manifest.

Comment: AAR solution is applicable when i have multiple NFC application installed in my phone and when i swipe NFC only one app to open (Without showing `choose an action` dialog). I understood through this [https://gototags.com/nfc/ndef/android-application/] post about AAR. Correct me if i'm wrong. In my case my app is showing all three activites in my app to choose.